# Failed to lookup view in Express MVC

Tags: node.js, express, view, pug, lookup

My express version is 4.13.1.
My express dir is that:
[image: express Dir]

#### app.js

```js
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use('/user',require('./controllers'));
```

#### controllers/index.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = module.exports = express.Router();
router.use('/signup', require('./signup'));
```

#### controllers/signup/index.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = module.exports = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('signup', { title: 'Signup' });
});
```

Then use 'http://localhost:3000/user/signup/' in browser,throw Error:
[image: Fail to lookup view]

I'm waiting online,thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify all directories which contain `views`, for example:

```
var views = [
      path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'controllers/signups/views')
];

app.set('views', views);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,userful.